What is the relationship between the silver ratio and the postion of a circle in the corner of a triangle?
I was recently trying to figure out how much to offset a circle in the corner of a right-angled triangle and found empirically that the x-offset needed to be around 2.414 which I later found to be the "silver ratio".
Which has the following formula:
$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(2 + \sqrt{2^2 + 4}\right)$

My question is how is the silver ratio related to the offset of a circle in a right-angled triangle?

If an illustrative image was embedded directly in the posted question, it would make the question easier to attack.  For help managing an image, see the Images section, at the bottom of
this article
and see also this article.

@user2661923 I can't without reputation.

Common problem.  You have done what you could, by addressing a comment to me, after you created the link.  I edited the question to embed the image directly in your posted question.

This is because the offset $(h)$ is the positive root of the quadratic equation $h^2-2h-1=0$ (same as the quadratic equation $\delta_S^2-2\delta_S-1=0$ satisfied by the silver ratio $\delta_S=1+\sqrt2$). The quadratic equation in $h$ can be derived as follows.
Substitute $y=x$ in the equation of the circle $(x-h)^2+(y-1)^2=1$ to find the point of intersection.
$$(x-h)^2+(x-1)^2=1\implies2x^2-2(h+1)x+h^2=0\tag{1}$$
Since the line $y=x$ is tangent to the circle, the equation $(1)$ must have equal roots. For this, the discriminant has to be zero, i.e., $2^2(h+1)^2-4\cdot2\cdot h^2=0\implies h^2-2h-1=0\implies \boxed{h=1+\sqrt2}$  since $h$ is positive (same as the silver ratio).
This can be geometrically visualized by introducing a regular octagon (unit side). A regular octagon can be fit, as shown in the image below. The octagon can be decomposed into a silver ratio rectangle (shaded rectangle). This shows that the offset is numerically equal to the silver ratio. 
PS: You can also derive that by taking derivative $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ (slope) at a point $(x,y)$ on the circle and equating it to $1$. Then, you will get the same quadratic equation in $h$ after substituting $y$ or $x$ (in terms of $h$) into the circle equation.
